# Does an increasing sequence always have a lower bound?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

In the proof that I am trying to understand, it says: let $a(n)$ be increasing, then $a(1)$ is less than or equal to $a(n)$ for all $n$, so the sequence is bounded below. Does that mean that an increasing sequence is always bounded below?

Comment: Yes.  What makes you doubt that?

Comment: thanks, i am new to analysis/proving

Comment: A very great deal of "analysis/proving" is understanding and **using** definitions!  A sequence always has a first member.  Since the sequence is increasing that first member is the smallest and so is not only a "lower bound" it is the "greatest lower bound".

Comment: alright, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Essentially a sequence being increasing means

$$a_1\leq a_2\leq a_3\leq a_4\ldots$$

Its clear that $\forall n\in \Bbb N, a_1\leq a_n$, hence $a_1$ is a lower bound.